# Show corresponding legend for second geom_point()

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-point

I am plotting three times with `geom_point` in the same plot but the second and third `geom_point` don't appear in the legend and I don't understand why. I looked at many posts but I can't find a solution that really works. My 2 original dataframes are different and I would prefer to keep it that way and not join them.

[image]

Either the cross (or the colour) appears on all the legend items or the second `geom_point()` is not mentionned to the legend. Here's my current code:

```
ggplot () +
  geom_point(data = data_1[data_1$River != "Roya",], aes(x = W_AC, y = BRI_mean_XS, shape = River, col = Type), size = 3) +
  geom_point(data = data_2, aes(x = W_m, y = BRI_norm, color = "Second geom_point "), shape = 4, size = 2.5) + 
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(15, 18, 17, 16)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("blue4", "chocolate1", "darkcyan")) +
  geom_text(data = data_1[data_1$River != "Roya",], aes(x = W_AC, y = BRI_mean_XS, label = Year, vjust = -0.5, hjust = -0.5), show.legend = FALSE, size = 4) +
  scale_x_continuous(name = "aa") +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "bb") + 
  geom_point(data = data_1[data_1$River == "Roya",], aes(x = W_AC, y = BRI_mean_XS), shape = 16, col = "cornflowerblue", size = 3) +
  geom_text(data = data_1[data_1$River == "Roya",], aes(x = W_AC, y = BRI_mean_XS, label = Year, vjust = -0.5, hjust = -0.5), show.legend = F, size = 4) +
  theme_bw()
```

I tried also to specify the colour and shape in the `scale_*_manual` but the shape is not used in the plot. For example: `scale_shape_manual(values = c(15, 18, 17, 16, 4))`, `4` being for the second geom_point.

As I read on other posts, when values are specified in `scale_*_manual`, it should appear after in the legend but here it seems mixed up. Is it not possible to show a blue cross in the `Type` section or the `River` section ? Same for the third `geom_point()` (Roya) is it possible to draw a blue circle in the `River` section?

Here's a dput of my 2 dataframes:

data_1:

```
structure(list(River = c("Durance", "Durance", "Durance", "Durance",  "Roya", "Var", "Drac", "Drac", "Drac", "Drac", "Var", "Var",  "Mareta", "Mareta", "Mareta", "Mareta", "Var"), Type = c("Under restoration",  "Target", "Under restoration", "Target", "Witness", "Under restoration",  "Under restoration", "Target", "Under restoration", "Target",  "Target", "Under restoration", "Under restoration", "Under restoration",  "Target", "Target", "Under restoration"), Year = c(2017, 2017,  2012, 2012, 2018, 2005, 2011, 2011, 2018, 2018, 2012, 2018, 2005,  2013, 2005, 2013, 2012), BRI_mean_XS = c(0.0028, 0.0017, 0.0033, 
0.0018, 0.009, 0.0097, 0.0182, 0.0026, 0.0032, 0.0035, 0.0053, 
0.0016, 0.005, 0.0041, 0.0058, 0.0082, 0.0037), W_AC = c(296.522411128284, 
411.01376146789, 263.944186046512, 363.288990825688, 88.6420798065296, 
155.868223887175, 41.4430051813472, 138.772532188841, 105.525906735751, 
108.848484848485, 144.78431372549, 314.685764654033, 29.8791208791209, 
52.8, 33.6949152542373, 34.4661016949153, 149.838539375275)), row.names = c(NA, 
-17L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

data_2:

```
structure(list(SITE = c("AIGUES-C", "BUECH-AV", "ARRONDINE",  "ARVAN", "ASSE-BLIEUX", "ASSE-BLIEUX", "ASSE-AV", "ASSE-AM",  "ASSE-AM", "BES-BLEONE", "BES-BLEONE", "BES-DROME", "BES-DROME",  "BLEONE-AM", "BLEONE-AV", "BUECH-AV", "BUECH-AV", "DRANSE-MORZINE",  "DRANSE-MORZINE", "DROME-RECOUBEAU", "DROME-PONTQUART", "DROME-PONTQUART",  "EYGUES-R", "FIER", "GIFFRE", "JABRON", "PETIT-BUECH", "PETIT-BUECH",  "ROUBION", "SASSE", "SASSE", "SASSE", "SEVERAISSE", "SEVERAISSE",  "UBAYE", "VANCON", "VAR", "VENEON", "VERDON", "DRAC LIDAR1",  "DROME LIDAR1", "DROME LIDAR2", "DROME LIDAR3"), W_m = c(180, 
333.593594745271, 56, 78, 102, 58.8, 171.9, 202, 170, 132, 148,  76, 98, 99.9, 171.3, 214, 125, 63, 64, 137, 181, 39, 66, 91,  220, 120, 90, 103, 114, 182, 123, 139, 152, 38, 144, 58, 183,  193, 193,
103.3287640678, 170.959110791, 168.800988262, 133.13237116 ), BRI_norm = c(0.00238417932933424, 0.0019586918252209, 0.00592873427970417, 
0.00496998572378169, 0.00257768461027533, 0.00594823420965329, 
0.00196839869925125, 0.00110647254938539, 0.00129282468469599, 
0.00255415705319677, 0.00189636185539575, 0.00272918083912772, 
0.00362898036424863, 0.00240398604859984, 0.00158558538418367, 
0.00179786294819712, 0.0024557284827885, 0.00910376733031885, 
0.00534776094775883, 0.00392598083437978, 0.00240750522409946, 
0.00514878385829154, 0.00254279813562245, 0.00563806058644668, 
0.00119537585167636, 0.00458318564753459, 0.00595336684669024, 
0.00487895959784154, 0.00292014352039067, 0.00238157929363119, 
0.0025305005154242, 0.00243334672392244, 0.00211201916980846, 
0.007410716639085, 0.0035528851408779, 0.00991898865707844, 0.00350148630982832, 
0.00181290043814611, 0.00277563808425691, 0.00766507891511477, 
0.000968375521552066, 0.000999909065815609, 0.00107669687622853 )), row.names = c(NA, -43L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame" ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm really not a big fan of the following approach (it would be more idiomatic to solve this using appropriate mappings) but you could solve this quickly by overriding the `color` / `shape` aesthetics in `River` and `Type` legends to your liking:

1. Modify your third point layer by moving the `shape` aesthetic inside `aes` and map from `River`:

```r
aes(x = W_AC, y = BRI_mean_XS, shape = River)
```

2. Adjust the shape scale such that `Roya` is represented by a circle (16):

```r
scale_shape_manual(values = c(15, 18, 17, 16, 16))
```

3. Override the aesthetics in the legend using `guides()`:

```
 + guides(
    color = guide_legend(
        override.aes = list(shape = c(4, 16, 16))
    ),
    shape = guide_legend(
        override.aes = list(color = c(rep("black", 3), "cornflowerblue", "black"))
    )
  )
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I hope this is a helpful step forward, but not entirely sure if it completes the plot you're looking for. In essence there are two further steps you should take to get everything in legends and everything in order:

- Anything you want to appear in the legends should be within each `aes()` call for each `geom_point()`
- using the `breaks =`  argument in the `scale_*_manual()` calls lets you both specify everything that should be displayed and the order it should be in.

Working with both of those, this might be the start of what you're looking for:

```r
library(ggplot2)

# the parts of the plot I haven't changed (separated for clarity)

p_base <- ggplot () +
  geom_text(
    data = data_1[data_1$River != "Roya", ],
    aes(
      x = W_AC,
      y = BRI_mean_XS,
      label = Year,
      vjust = -0.5,
      hjust = -0.5
    ),
    show.legend = FALSE,
    size = 4
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(name = "aa") +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "bb") +
  geom_text(
    data = data_1[data_1$River == "Roya", ],
    aes(
      x = W_AC,
      y = BRI_mean_XS,
      label = Year,
      vjust = -0.5,
      hjust = -0.5
    ),
    show.legend = F,
    size = 4
  ) +
  theme_bw()

# Parts I've changed

p_base + geom_point(
  data = data_1[data_1$River != "Roya",],
  aes(
    x = W_AC,
    y = BRI_mean_XS,
    shape = River,
    col = Type
  ),
  size = 3
) +
  geom_point(
    data = data_2,
    aes(
      x = W_m,
      y = BRI_norm,
      shape = "Second geom_point",
      color = "Second geom_point"
    ),
    size = 2.5
  ) +
  scale_shape_manual(
    breaks = c("Drac", "Durance", "Mareta", "Roya", "Var", "Second geom_point"),
    values = c(15, 18, 17, 16, 10, 4)
  ) +
  scale_colour_manual(
    breaks = c("Target", "Under restoration", "Second geom_point", "Roya"),
    values = c("blue4", "chocolate1", "darkcyan", "cornflowerblue")
  ) +
  geom_point(
    data = data_1[data_1$River == "Roya",],
    aes(
      x = W_AC,
      y = BRI_mean_XS,
      shape = "Roya",
      col = "Roya"
    ),
    size = 3
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Also, if it is really necessary to have the Roya in the legend for Shape as a cornflowerblue circle, it can probably be achieved using the `guides()` function, described [here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/guides.html). Feels a bit messy, though.